# Replace a sign in a RegularExpression

Tags: regex

Might be very easy but it is to early for me. :-)

I have this

```
 Value="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace( $(str)
              , '^(\d+)\.(.+)\.\d+$', '$1_$2' ) )">
```

- Input: `2.5.1057.140509`
- which will come out like this: `2_5.1057`

What I need is to have a regex so it becomes `2_5.1057.140509`

HOW?

Comment: What's your input string? What implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You forget to append the remaining part to the result.

Change it to:

```
Value="$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace( $(str)
                , '^(\d+)\.(.+)\.(\d+$)', '$1_$2.$3' ) )"> 
                                 ^^^^^^         ^^^
```